# SQL query entering identical records

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, insert

I have a SQL insert query in my project, and it works fine, in fact, perhaps a little too well, as it saves the data I entered, but saves it twice, each with two different ID autonumbers. Can anybody work out why?

// Save button code

```
Private Sub buttonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim incidentSolved As Boolean = False

    If cboxSolved.Checked Then
        incidentSolved = True
    End If

    If txtClientSave.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Client name cannot be blank")

    ElseIf rtbProblem.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Problem cannot be blank")

    ElseIf cboxSolved.Checked = True And rtbSolution.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter solution")

    Else
        database.SaveNewIncident(txtClientSave.Text, dtpStart.Value, dtpEnd.Value, rtbProblem.Text, dtpStartTime.Value, dtpEndTime.Value, cboxSolved.Checked, rtbSolution.Text, _con)

        MsgBox("Save successful")

        txtClientSave.Text = ""
        rtbProblem.Text = ""
        rtbSolution.Text = ""
        dtpStart.Value = Date.Today
        dtpEnd.Value = Date.Today
        dtpStartTime.Value = DateTime.Now
        dtpEndTime.Value = DateTime.Now
        cboxSolved.Checked = False

    End If

    loadIncidents()

End Sub
```

// Save SQL

```
Public Shared Function SaveNewIncident(ByVal clientName As String, dateStart As Date, dateEnd As Date, ByVal incidentProblem As String, ByVal timeStart As String, ByVal timeEnd As String, ByVal incidentSolved As Boolean, ByVal incidentSolution As String, _Con As OleDbConnection)

    Dim tr As OleDbTransaction = Nothing

    Try
        tr = _Con.BeginTransaction()

        Dim Dc As New OleDbCommand
        Dc.Connection = _Con

        Dc.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblIncidents VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        Dc.Transaction = tr
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@clientName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = clientName
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@dateStart", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateStart
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@dateEnd", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateEnd
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@incidentProblem", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = incidentProblem
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@timeStart", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timeStart
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@timeEnd", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timeEnd
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@incidentSolved", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = incidentSolved
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@incidentSolution", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = incidentSolution
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@SSMA_TimeStamp", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp)

        Dim supportID As Integer
        Dim Ds As New OleDbCommand

        Ds.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Ds.CommandText = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS supportID"
        Ds.Transaction = tr

        supportID = CType(Dc.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
        Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()

        tr.Commit()

    Catch ex As Exception

        mdInit.errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        MsgBox("Failed to save data, refer to error log")
        tr.Rollback()

    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
supportID = CType(Dc.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()   'you are doing it a second time here
```

there it is, you are executing it twice

comment out your second one

```
     supportID = CType(Dc.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
    'Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

the problem is in SaveNewIncident, you execute a scalar and get the supportId generated, then you execute the whole thing again as a nonquery - both are valid ways of executing your commands, but both the INSERT and SELECT commands are executed both times (in the second execute, ExecuteNonQuery, you don't pick up the value selected)

---

how about

```
Public Shared Function SaveNewIncident(ByVal clientName As String, dateStart As Date, dateEnd As Date, ByVal incidentProblem As String, ByVal timeStart As String, ByVal timeEnd As String,
                                   ByVal incidentSolved As Boolean, ByVal incidentSolution As String, _Con As OleDbConnection)

Dim tr As OleDbTransaction = Nothing

Try
    tr = _Con.BeginTransaction()

    Dim Dc As New OleDbCommand
    Dc.Connection = _Con

    Dc.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblIncidents VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    Dc.Transaction = tr
    Dc.Parameters.Add("@clientName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = clientName
    Dc.Parameters.Add("@dateStart", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateStart
    Dc.Parameters.Add("@dateEnd", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateEnd
    Dc.Parameters.Add("@incidentProblem", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = incidentProblem
    Dc.Parameters.Add("@timeStart", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timeStart
    Dc.Parameters.Add("@timeEnd", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timeEnd
    Dc.Parameters.Add("@incidentSolved", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = incidentSolved
    Dc.Parameters.Add("@incidentSolution", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = incidentSolution
    Dc.Parameters.Add("@SSMA_TimeStamp", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp)

    Dim supportID As Integer
    Dc.CommandText += ";SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS supportID"

    supportID = CType(Dc.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)

    tr.Commit()

Catch ex As Exception

    mdInit.errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
    MsgBox("Failed to save data, refer to error log")
    tr.Rollback()

End Try
```

End Function

there is also a mix up between ds and dc

Answer (score 0):

Just comment `Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()` as it's already executing query in `Dc.ExecuteScalar()`